# React parsing Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having some problems with my React code.
I'm trying to add authentication but it's giving me error like

> ./src/components/UserInfo/index.js   Line 29:  Parsing error:
>   Unexpected token, expected ","
>
> 27 |    28 |
>
> > 29 |        {authenticated ? (
> >          |        ^   30 |                  31 |                    32 |

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Avatar, Popover } from "antd";
import { userSignOut } from "appRedux/actions/Auth";

class UserInfo extends Component {

  render() {
    const { authenticated } = this.props;

    const userMenuOptions = (
      <ul className="gx-user-popover">
        <li>My Account</li>
        <li>Connections</li>
        <li onClick={() => this.props.userSignOut()}>Logout
        </li>
      </ul>
    );

    return (
       {authenticated ? (
              <Popover overlayClassName="gx-popover-horizantal" placement="bottomRight" content={userMenuOptions}
                trigger="click">
                <Avatar src={require("assets/images/w-logo.png")}
                  className="gx-avatar gx-pointer" alt="" />
              </Popover>
            ) : (
                <Popover overlayClassName="gx-popover-horizantal" placement="bottomRight" content={userMenuOptions}
                  trigger="click">
                  <Avatar src={require("assets/images/w-logo.png")}
                    className="gx-avatar gx-pointer" alt="" />
                </Popover>
              )}

    )

  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  //console.log(state.auth.token);
  return {
    authenticated: state.auth.token !== null,
    locale: state.settings.locale
  }
}





export default connect(mapStateToProps, { userSignOut })(UserInfo);
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem lies in that line because you are returning

```
return (
    {authenticated ? (...) : (...)});
```

Which means, that you're trying to return an object, and that's not what you actually want. So you should change it to this:

```
return authenticated ? (
          <Popover overlayClassName="gx-popover-horizantal" placement="bottomRight" content={userMenuOptions}
            trigger="click">
            <Avatar src={require("assets/images/w-logo.png")}
              className="gx-avatar gx-pointer" alt="" />
          </Popover>
        ) : (
            <Popover overlayClassName="gx-popover-horizantal" placement="bottomRight" content={userMenuOptions}
              trigger="click">
              <Avatar src={require("assets/images/w-logo.png")}
                className="gx-avatar gx-pointer" alt="" />
            </Popover>
          );
```